# Compare two HashMaps keys for equality?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, collections, compareto

I have two `HashMap<HashSet<String>, Long>` that I want to compare based on the Key. The Key is a `HashSet<String>`, I might need to change to `TreeSet<String>` but I don't think it is necessary. How would I compare these?

NOTE: The Map is just used as a wrapper around a single Set.

```
for(HashMap<HashSet<String>, Long> entry : ListOfMaps) {
    if(entry.keySet().equals(entry2.keySet())) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I want to check the Set1.equals(Set2).

The set must be exactly the same. Since there is only one `Set<String>` in each `HashMap<Set<String>, Long>` it makes me nervous that I am grabbing all the Keys, or is this okay?

Comment: What you've got there should work, according to the javadoc
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Cool, just making sure since I only have one set in each.

Comment: Note that `HashSets` are not ordered, so a `.equals()` call is just going to ensure that all of the strings in the first set are also present in the second

Comment: Right. But it will check all the strings in each HashSet to make sure they are equal or is it just comparing the order.

Comment: Set[A, B, C] would equal Set[B, C, A] right?

Comment: Correct.  <meaningless text to fill in the required character count to reply> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals() contract of Set says:

> Returns true if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Set interface.

So your code will work as long as the Set implementation follows the contract.

However, this may be dangerous depending on what your code does with the Sets that are used as keys.  Once an object is used as a key in a Map, it shouldn't change because that breaks the contract of Map.

```
Map<Set<String>, T> map = HashMap<>();
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();

mySet.add("first");
map.put(mySet, myValue);


Set<String> copyOfMySet = new HashSet<>(mySet);

//returns true
map.contains(copyOfMySet);

//modifying mySet
mySet.remove("first");

//this will now return false
map.contains(copyOfMySet);
```

Comment: I am just using the Map as a wrapper around a set and a timestamp.

Comment: Generally speaking I personally avoid using Sets, Lists, etc as keys for maps as it's far to easy to break things... As the author of this comment points out :)

Comment: Much better to use simple variables, like ints, strings, etc if at all possible

Comment: Another reason for not using set here or any collection might be the complexity of this equality operation. If you use any string or int as key then comparing two hashmaps will be of O(nm) where n is key length and m is number of keys. Now if you use hashset, then it will be O(nm*pq) where p is Set's key length and q is number of keys. Let  me know your views if i am missing something here.